# Django ModelForm initial doesn't work unless in <form>

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Maybe I'm going from a bad approach but suppose this generic scenario:

I have blogs which has comments. The blog page has a form for creating comments. Comments have a ModelForm, the actual HTML is done selectively. The foreign key is of course not visible or rendered. On submit, the comment's foreign key needs to be associated with the blog.

If I use initial with the blog foreign key with the comment ModelForm, it doesn't persist in the POST. Makes sense since it's not in the form tag.

I can attach it after the POST in the view that form calls but ModelForm(request.POST).data is not mutable. I can do ModelForm(request.POST).save(commit=False) but it means the comment's model's foreign key to blog can be blank which doesn't really make sense from a model's point of view.

What's the proper way of doing this? Seems like a pretty standard usage.

Thanks

Comment: one thought: create new comment model instance with the right foreign key, call modelform constructor with the new model instance and the post data, then save. This avoids saving twice which feels a bit weird (pure personal opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
def add_comment(request, blog_id):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, blog_id)

    comment = Comment(blog=blog)

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        form = CommentForm(instance=comment)

    context = { 'blog':blog,
                'form':form, }

    return render_to_response('add-comment.html', context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: how can I make sure comment.blog doesn't get overwritten by a hacked POST?

Comment: what do you mean a hacked POST?

Comment: well the intent is that user POST doesn't include anything like {'blog_id': 100} because the form tag doesn't contain anything 'blog_id' related but an atypical user can put just about anything in POST and can put an id. If the comment instance has a blog_id and the POST has a blog_id as well, can I prevent overwriting?

Comment: exclude the blog field from your form in the Meta. An atypical user can put anything he wants into the POST but only fields included in the form are looked at.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your view knows which Blog instance it is dealing with.

```
# get an unsaved comment instance
comment = form.save(commit=False)

# set the foreign key to blog
comment.blog = blog

# save it to the db
comment.save()
```

This is the standard way of doing it.  Yes your comment instance's foreign key to Blog is None for a short time, but this doesn't matter as long as you don't save it (or null=True is set on the FK definition).  The commit=False means it doesn't hit the database, which is why you have to save the comment manually later.